# Windows phone 8 xaudio2 wav file issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, wav, xaudio2

I want play a wav file with XAudio2, I have searched on the internet and have some example projects like this: [C# XAudio2 Sound Playback for Windows Phone](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-xaudio2-sound-playback-for-windows.html) or this: [Play wav example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Audio-Sample-9a5bb0b7) but all those playing special wav files, if I replace my wav (converted to MS ADPCM, mono) then `CreateSourceVoice` return HRESULT 0x88960001. So what are specials of those wav files? or any other methods to play Wav file with xaudio2 (I'm working on windows phone 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article, the XAudio2 only supports a subset of the MS ADPCM format:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415711(v=vs.85).aspx

You have to use the adpcmencode tool in the Windows 8 SDK to compress it into something useable

Comment: Thanks you verymuch, I have spent all day to figure out what happend and now it solved! Thanks you again ;)

Answer (score 1):

So the standard way of playing both sound effects and background music is using the XNA library.

I wrote a blog post on [playing async sound in the windows phone](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=60) that is pretty straight forward

Basically it says this

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

static Stream stream1 = TitleContainer.OpenStream("soundeffect.wav");
static SoundEffect sfx = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream1);
static SoundEffectInstance soundEffect = sfx.CreateInstance();

public void playSound(){
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    soundEffect.Play();
}
```

Doesn't get any easier than that. To get specific wav requirements look at the [MSDN page for supported formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I also posted a working solution for download on my blog post.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but it seem XNA doesn't in developing anymore and I can't add XNA to my windows phone 8 project with NuGet :-(

Comment: Yes you can... You just need to add a reference to it.

Comment: XNA is not being developed anymore by microsoft but you can still use the libraries. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003(v=vs.105).aspx